# Laravel queue remove jobs

Tags: laravel, queue, beanstalkd

Is there a way to kill/remove a job that are already on the reserve?
Say I have 5 jobs that I pushed on the queue and the queue is currently processing the 2nd Job, but I want to cancel the processing of the 2nd job. Not all the jobs should be killed/removed just the 2nd one if my request would be to remove that.
I'm using beanstalkd for this queuing by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Beanstalkd console.

This one is pretty good: https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console

Comment: Is there any other way to remove jobs other than using a console? The job I am executing has many functions executed within it, I want to be able to make a web base user interface to cancel a on-going job.